# Python multiply value inside string

Tags: python, python-3.x

From web link I want to create pagination number for same link, for ex.

`link="https://www.example.com?id=s-25"`

so if my pagination count 5 then output should like this

```
"https://www.example.com?id=s-25"
"https://www.example.com?id=s-50"
"https://www.example.com?id=s-75"
"https://www.example.com?id=s-100"
"https://www.example.com?id=s-125"
```

I tried following code

```
link="https://www.example.com?id=s-25*{value}"

for i in range(1,5):

    print(link.format(value=i))
```

but it print output like

```
https://www.example.com?id=s-25*1
https://www.example.com?id=s-25*2
https://www.example.com?id=s-25*3
https://www.example.com?id=s-25*4
```

it's not multiply by value if I used `eval` like this

`print(eval(link.format(value=i)))`

got error

```
    print(eval(link.format(value=i)))
  File "<string>", line 1
    https://www.example.com?id=s-25*1
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or if you can't modify variable `link`, try:

```
link="https://www.example.com?id=s-25*{value}"
for i in range(1, 6):
    print(link[:link.rfind('-') + 1] + str(eval(link.format(value=i)[link.rfind('-') + 1:].format(value=i))))
```

Output:

```
https://www.example.com?id=s-25
https://www.example.com?id=s-50
https://www.example.com?id=s-75
https://www.example.com?id=s-100
https://www.example.com?id=s-125
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for i in range(1,6):
    print(f'https://www.example.com?id=s-{25*i}')
```

Output:

```
https://www.example.com?id=s-25
https://www.example.com?id=s-50
https://www.example.com?id=s-75
https://www.example.com?id=s-100
https://www.example.com?id=s-125
```

OR:

```
list(map("https://www.example.com?id=s-{}".format, range(25,150,25)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    for it in range(1, 6):
        print(f'https://www.example.com?id=s-{25*it}')
```